# C#: thread makes crash with blue screen

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, crash

In my project I am using thread to search via bluetooth devices.But when it searchs some times it crashs and appears ble screan.I couldent read all because it restarts computer but I saw that it is abour some ram blocks. X8001 something like this.Is thread couse this?Or I am also using database Mysql.When it searchs it also gets value from database.

Comment: Provide max details tht u can. What were u doing? Wht is ur analysis? Any sample code available to be shared here?

Comment: My program using bluetooth searches nearest bluetooth devices and look that are their Mac addresses exist in database or not.And it can finds the which person exists or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# cannot cause BSODs.  Bluetooth device drivers certainly do, there are a lot of crummy ones out there.  Screw up spell checkers too.  Post to superuser.com to get help finding updates or better BT stacks.

Comment: I am using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.dll library.For BT driver I did not installed any.I bought some little bluetooth device and only plug to computer.It recognized.

Comment: true so long as you never touch the 'unsafe' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

BSOD should be diagnosed easily with crash dump analysis. Then you can know who breaks the system, and how to move on.

Well, if you cannot DIY, you can consider open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and involve Microsoft support team.